# How i use Recycle View in lower Android API level?

Tags: android

When using Recycle view in Android Application as latest version like API level 23 or above,recycle view run successfully,so how i use Recycle view in lower android version like 4.0?

Comment: Since it is a part of appcompact, it has backward compatibility for android versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView is the part of v7.
So you can use it with API level 7 or higher.

Description about android supported libraries http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_support_library.htm

May this helps you.